# What are all of the drops from the Pumpking in the Pumpkin Moon Event?

Tags: terraria

So far, I've defeated the Pumpking a few times and was lucky to get the Raven Staff. I just want to know now what all I can get from the boss. I heard I could get the Horseman's Blade from him.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the following items with drop rates:

- The Horseman's Blade (1.79-14.29%)
- Bat Scepter (1.79-14.29%)
- Black Fairy Dust (1.79-14.29%)
- Spider Egg (1.79-14.29%)
- Raven Staff (1.79-14.29%)
- Candy Corn Rifle (1.79-14.29%)
- Jack 'O Lantern Launcher (1.79-14.29%)
- Pumpking Trophy (Wave 15 (10-15 in Expert Mode) only) (100%)

[Source](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pumpking)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Terraria Wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pumpking), his potential drops are:

- The Horseman's Blade
- Bat Scepter
- Black Fairy Dust
- Spider Egg
- Raven Staff
- Candy Corn Rifle/Candy Corn
- Jack 'O Lantern Launcher/Explosive Jack 'O Lantern
- Pumpking Trophy

The Pumpking trophy has a 100% chance drop. All other items have a 1.79% (14.29%  in expert mode) chance drop.